# Using steam web api to access how many times players are reported for hacking

Tags: steam, steam-web-api

Would it be possible to keep track of every time a csgo player gets reported (for hacking) through the Steam WebAPI.

In other words does valve give stats on how many times players have been reported for aim or wall hacking through Steam WebAPI.

Is something like this possible or does valve not give access to this information real-time?

Answer (score 0):

Steam doesn't release that information to the public. Although you can see if a player has a VAC Ban.